# In Haskell can you have functions that return nothing?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell can you have functions that return nothing?
If so, is there an example of this?

Comment: By "nothing", do you mean the `Nothing` constructor from the `Maybe` type, the `()` constructor from the `()` type, or a bottom value from the `Void` type?

Comment: from the void type

Comment: The `Void` type has no values that exhibit it, so no, you cannot have a function that returns `Void`.

Comment: @Aplet123 Oh really? `error` is a function, isn't it?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Using `error` to return `Void` can hardly be considered a useful scenario.

Comment: How are you getting `error` to return at all?

Comment: @Soprano Note that Haskell's `Void` is completely different from C's `void`. The closest to C's `void` in Haskell is `()`. And, yes, we can write `f :: a -> ()` as `f _ = ()`. For completeness, we can also write functions returning `Void`, but these must either fail to terminate successfully, or take "contradictory" arguments which lead to `Void`, e.g. `f :: Void -> Void ; f x = x` or `g :: a -> (a -> Void) -> Void ; g x h = h x`.

Comment: I don't get why did this question get downvoted.

Answer (score 11):

No. However, you can have functions that return a trivial value. The `()` type has only one inhabitant, `()`. This is about as analogous to C's concept of a `void` return as it gets. (I have always felt that `void` was a bad name, because conceptually there really is one inhabitant not zero.)

Here's the standard function that returns `()`:

```
foo :: Int -> String -> ()
foo _ _ = ()
```

This one doesn't look too useful, but there actually can be functions that return `()` and are useful, like [`rnf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.4.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:rnf).

However, in *almost all* situations where this question arises, you will be much more excited by the `IO ()` type. This is the type of procedures that do some interesting interaction with the world, but don't produce any interesting information to consume later. There are many, many more inhabitants of the type `IO ()` than there are of the type `()`. For example:

```
bar :: IO ()
bar = do
    putStrLn "What's your name?"
    s <- getLine
    putStrLn $ "Hello, " ++ s ++ "!"
```

But a word on terminology: this is not a "function" in the way that most people use that word -- after all, it can not be passed any arguments!

The two features -- functions and procedures -- can be profitably mixed. If you are getting the name from somewhere else than the command line, you might want to parameterize the procedure above, like this:

```
baz :: String -> IO ()
baz name = putStrLn $ "Hello, " ++ name ++ "!"
```

This is a function that returns a procedure, and that procedure interacts with the world and then produces an uninteresting `()` value.